# Visual Studio - Software 64Bits

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bits

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para um software que fiz no visual studio seja executável em Windows 64 bits. Já procurei nas opções algum lugar para compilar para 64 bits mas não tive certezas.

Alguém conhece esse processo?

Comment: Em que linguagem?

Comment: Até onde sei as versões do Windows que são 64 bits devem executar software para Windows 32 bits sem problema algum.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve definir a plataforma nas opções de Build da sua aplicação.

Clicka com o botão direito no projeto (não na solution) e vai em propriedades e alterar como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O "Any CPF", em tese é pra funcionar em qualquer plataforma (x64/x86), no seu caso então é só colocar em x64 e compilar o projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Selecione seu projeto:

1- Botao direito (Propriedades)

2- Seção de Build

3- CPU (Selecione x64)

[image: Tutorial]